# Add tool-tips to documentation icons?

Tags: feature-request, documentation

When searching documentation, there are 2 types of search results that could be returned (example or topic). Is it possible to add tool tips to these for clarity?

See image:

[image]

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I think there the docs only have the two different symbols you already mentioned: the code symbol (`<>`) which means that it is an *example* and the doc symbol  (`|<> |`) which stands for a *topic side* containing examples.

Comment: I was thinking Syntax, Parameters, Remarks, but it looks like search results there return the parent topic. Looks like just the 2, you are correct

Comment: Keep in mind it will mention the number of examples if it is a topic, similar to searching Q&A.

Comment: @elegent better for the blind though (though I'm not sure how the blind would code :P) wait nvm (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118984/how-can-you-program-if-youre-blind)

Comment: @Laurel: Yep it’s actually very similar to the Q/A search result – it seems like that they only replaced the `Q:<title of the asked question>` and the `A:<title of the answered question>` with the two symbols and the corresponding title of the example or topic  … ;)

Comment: Why don’t call things as they are and display `Example` or `Topic` above the title of the post?